# cam3 doesn't load in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

In the **Measurement and Automation Explorer**, it shows up and seems to work fine, but for some reason I can't seem to load it with IMAQ in a LabVIEW program. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this working ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- IMAQ can't open cameras in MAX and LabVIEW at the same time. So close MAX (or click onto another camera...)
- Try to load it with the Vision Express Acquisition vi in LabVIEW, then turn it into LV code (Right mouse, create front panel)
- IMAQ or IMAQdx?

Comment: MAX is closed and I'm using the IMAQdx Examples.llb located in the IMAX examples. I'm not sure what you mean by Vision Express Axquisition vi? It still doesnt pop up under the options =/ Many many thanks for the help on this!

Comment: Open a new vi, not an example. There is an Express vi in your block diagram - functions menu. It is under Vision+Motion -> Vision Express -> Vision Acquisition. Follow the instructions/assistant.

Comment: This works! But why doesnt it show up for the IMAQdx? Even when I type in the name manually, it complains that it cant find the camera.

Comment: I do not know how you configure the IMAQdx - and I do not know how the example is configured. Just right-click on your Express vi and "Open Front Panel"- There you see how it should work. It's not perfect code, but it's good to have a running piece of code to start with.